# Modify values that are received via Feeds_ex

Tags: feeds

I've setup Feeds_ex module using JSONPath. One of the value I import is language code and it has next format: [language-country], i.e. [en-US] or [en-UK].

Right now I do import full value 'en-US', however I need to get only 'en' and get ridd of '-US'.

What is the good/best practice to modify value that I receive from Feed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [hook_feeds_presave()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_presave/7).

Just explore $entity object. You will get some idea.

Below is a example code.

```
$entity->lang_country[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'en'; 
// After split [language-country] store your lang here.
```

**Update**:
Also check [feeds_tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper)

Comment: Thanks, that would work, however I believe this task is already solved somehow.
I've found module 'feeds_tamper' and it looks like it does what I need. Is it OK to use it?

Comment: Yes correct. `feeds_tamper` to sanitize feeds input. If this answer is useful, please flag as a useful answer.

Comment: please update your answer wit feeds_tamper module and I will accept it as an answer.